# Adding Gesture Recognizer for panning a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

After seeing some examples, I'm trying to create a window where an Image view could be moved with the PanGestureRecognizer. I don't understand what is missing.

- I created and initialized an UIView object
- I also created an UIGestureRecognizer for panning, for both views.
- I created the method to be selected when Gesture is recognized.

If you have an idea of what is missing, I would be thankful to read it;

Here is my code:

View Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "bouton.h"

@interface ATSViewController : UIViewController {
    boutonHome *bouton; }

@property (retain, nonatomic) boutonHome *bouton;

-(IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender;

@end
```

View Controller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    // Set self's frame to encompass the image
    bouton.frame = frame;
    bouton.boutonImage = image;

    [self.view addSubview:bouton];  

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];

    [bouton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [bouton addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(IBAction)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CGPoint translate = [sender translationInView:self.view]; 

    CGRect newFrame = bouton.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x += translate.x;
    newFrame.origin.y += translate.y;
    sender.view.frame = newFrame;

    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    bouton.frame = newFrame;
}
```

BoutonHome.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface boutonHome : UIView
{
    UIImage *boutonImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *boutonImage;


// Initializer for this object


@end
```

boutonHome.m

```
#import "bouton.h"

@implementation boutonHome

@synthesize boutonImage;


@end
```

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more

Comment: Just check this link i hope its will solve your problem. http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more and second link if previous not solve problem. http://www.icodeblog.com/tag/uigesturerecognizers/

Comment: you have added gesture to self.view i think you just have to add gesture to only that element which you willing to move dont add it to whole view